# Android 6.0 permissions error Toast

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am updating the app I am working on to work on Android 6.0.
In the beginning the app would crash, but updating the gradle file to use the newest versions of external libs (intercom and GCM services) did the trick and the app runs smoothly.
The only problem is that on startup a Toast message is displayed with the text: "Please specify next permissions in your manifest file: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
The permission is of course written in the manifest file.
I am assuming this has something to do with the runtime permissions mechanism that Android 6.0 introduces (the message doesn't appear when running with older version of Android).

Another annoying little issue is that the toast message doesn't appear when running with a debugger (using Android Studio 1.4).

How can I know what is causing this Toast to appear? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this issue in my project as well, and it turns out that the toast is from ubertesters SDK, I decompiled the jar file and this is what I found.

```
package com.ubertesters.sdk.utility;

public class StringProvider {
    public StringProvider() {
    }

    public static String addPermission() {
        return "Please specify next permissions in your manifest file: ";
    }

    public static String installLatestVersion() {
        return "Please, install the latest Ubertesters Hub version.";
    }

    public static String install() {
        return "Install";
    }
}
```

I will suggest you to exclude ubertesters SDK in your release product flavour and you won't see this toast in the release build.

Ubertesters has not updated its Android SDK for more than a year ... http://ubertesters.com/knowledge-base/android-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Ubertesters is constantly updating SDK for Android. The issue with handling permissions on Android 6.0 is successfully fixed in the next SDK version.
Please feel free to check and user our latest SDK available on the website http://ubertesters.com/knowledge-base/android-sdk/